# I want to combine date and time and compare with utc date

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

When I write this query

```
SELECT Convert(datetime,Convert(varchar,CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE))+' '+ 
       CONVERT(varchar, cast(meas_pain.datetime AS time))) FROM meas_pain
```

it works for me  but when I use the same part in WHERE clause it gives error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

```
SELECT schedules.id 
FROM meas_pain LEFT JOIN schedules ON schedules.id=meas_pain.schd_id 
WHERE meas_pain.schd_id=9150 AND  
      Convert(datetime,(Convert(varchar,CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE))+' '+
      CONVERT(varchar, cast(meas_pain.datetime AS time)))) < 
      CONVERT(datetime,DATEADD(Minute,0,getutcdate()))
```

can anybody explain??

Comment: Your query is with lot of unwanted conversions. Get rid of them, it will be easy to crack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why this error does not appear in your select statement, since I can reproduce the error using just

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE)))
```

**[Example of Error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8995)**

You are relying on localised conversion settings, you should use explicit conversion, e.g.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE), 111), 111)
```

By explicitly defining the date format to convert both to varchar and from varchar (111) you can avoid any implied conversions.

**However**, If your dates/times are stored as such there should be no need for all the conversion to and from varchar, this is just more chance for things to go wrong, and unnecessary work, you can simply add a time to a datetime. e.g.

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 1, GETUTCDATE()),
        @Date2 DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETUTCDATE());

SELECT  [Date1] = @Date1,
        [Date2] = @Date2,
        [Date1/Time2] = CAST(CAST(@Date1 AS DATE) AS DATETIME) +
                           CAST(@Date2 AS TIME);
```

From what I can gather from your query you are just trying to get results where the time of `meas_pain.datetime` is less that the current UTC time, regardless of date. So you should be able to simplify your query to just:

```
SELECT  schedules.id 
FROM    meas_pain 
        LEFT JOIN schedules 
            ON schedules.id = meas_pain.schd_id 
WHERE   meas_pain.schd_id = 9150
AND     CAST(meas_pain.[DateTime] AS TIME) < CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS TIME);
```

And remove further redundant conversions.

**[Simplified example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff96b/1)**

**ADENDUM**

Apparently this time comparison is not what you are after (although it is what the query you have posted is doing), so I am assuming GETUTCDATE() is just for demonstration.

The conversion you are trying to perform is equivalent to this:

```
CAST(CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(meas_pain.[DateTime] AS TIME)
```

**[Another example on SQL Fiddle using the above conversion](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff96b/3)**

Comment: i want to compare time for particular date only this will compare the all the time

Comment: Thanks this one worked for me i cant able to vote up you as my reputation is low thanks a lot